# What is the purpose of having the stub class on RMI client?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rmi, stub

What is the point of dynamically loading the stub class onto the RMI client? The stub which acts as a proxy for remote object is used by the client to call remote methods, but if we load the stub class, we have the class in the client VM. Doesn't this make it like a local method call, since the client has the entire stub class?

[Dynamic class loading RMI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/codebase.html)
[image]

Comment: ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I am sorry can you elaborate bit more? I didn't get you.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the point of dynamically loading the stub class onto the RMI client?

It simplifies the deployment problem. You don't have to distribute the stub class. Since dynamic stubs were introduced in Java 1.5, dynamic stub loading is of diminished importance.

> Doesn't this make it like a local method call, since the client has the entire stub class?

Of course, but then the called method in the stub class engages in the RMI network protocol to delegate it to the remote object.